# mvn create または mvn generate を実行する際にプロジェクトの作成場所を明示的に指定する方法

Tags: java, maven

##### 実行環境

M1 Mac
Java 6
Maven 2

#### 質問内容

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.example.myproject -DartifactId=myproject
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example.myproject -DartifactId=myproject
```

こんな感じで新規プロジェクトの作成をしたいです。
その際に作成するProjectのパスを指定したいのですが方法ありますか？

#### 背景

M1だとそもそもmvnコマンドがSegmentation faultで落ちてしまいます。
Javaのバイナリーがあるディレクトリでmvnコマンドを実行するとこのエラーを避けることができると記事で読んだのですが、Javaのバイナリと同じディレクトリにmvnの新規プロジェクトを作るのは避けたいため上記の質問をしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outputDirectory`を指定することにより出力ディレクトリを指定することができます。

例：

```
mvn -B archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quicks
tart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DoutputDirectory=/foo/bar
```

- 参考リンク

  - [archetype:generate](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html)